# Tips to find the rated voltage of the induction motor without nameplate data

Tags: voltage, induction-motor

I am doing a project in which I need to find the parameters without nameplate data of the induction motor. I am looking into finding a way/method to find the rated voltage of motor. Can I get any tips?

Comment: And it is a 3-ph induction motor

Comment: Do you know anything about it? If so, please share.

Comment: i have found the synchronous speed of the motor, and with the frequency, number of poles can be found also. this is what i have done so far

Comment: Do you have the  ability to force the motor to spin at the synchronous speed using another motor?

Comment: Most likely, I should not have problem for that but may I know the purpose of that? I have to explain to the lab tech before conducting such experiments.

Comment: If you spin it up to synchronous speed, it will probably generate voltage that is approximately the same as the nameplate voltage.
http://www.redrok.com/cimtext.pdf

Comment: @mkeith No, it probably won't.  Induction motors as a rule don't have permanent magnets to generate a rotating field, so no induced voltage.  Get some more details... How many wires are in the connection box? 3? 6? 9? What are they labeled?

Comment: @RDrast, if you add capacitance as per the link I put in my previous comment it will spin up and generate voltage. It is a well documented phenomenon.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks. I see that the documents says it is for 60Hz. Is it the same for 50Hz?

Comment: @JoelNandha, the basic theory is the same, yes. Perhaps the capacitor table is not quite right for 50 Hz, but I don't think the system is very sensitive to the capacitor value. Mind you, I have never done this. I have only read about it and watched videos.

Comment: I believe the voltage produced is sensitive to both the capacitance and to the load, but I could not find a better reference than the one provided by mkeith. You should try both suggested methods and compare the results. Try more than one capacitor value.

Answer (score 3):

First measure the motor and compare the measurements to NEMA and/or IEC tables of standard dimensions to determine whether it is likely to be a standard NEMA or IEC motor. Determine the standard voltage, frequency, speed and power ratings that might apply to a motor of that size.

Examine the motor leads or terminals. Determine if the number of leads or terminals allows for connecting the motor for more than one voltage. Find standard connection diagrams and connect the motor for the highest possible voltage.

For this kind of project, you should have a variable transformer of sufficient size to supply half of the probable rated current. The motor shaft should not be coupled to any load. Connect the motor at the lowest voltage setting of the transformer. Record the voltage, current and speed of the motor. Plot the voltage and current on a graph. Keep increasing the voltage and plotting the current until you notice the the current is increasing more quickly than the voltage increases. At that point, the applied voltage is probably 20 or 30 percent above the rated voltage. Pick the standard IEC or NEMA voltage that lies on the appropriate area of the curve.

If you are applying 50 Hz to a NEMA motor or 60 Hz to an IEC motor, adjust your estimate using rated 50 Hz voltage = 5/6 X rated 60 Hz voltage.

[Added PDF reference for above.](http://www.easa.com/sites/files/accreditation_program/NoLoadCurrentBasics_0205.pdf)

Something to try after you have a preliminary determination of the voltage rating:

If you can run a dynamometer test, you can plot voltage vs. current for a load torque that is carefully held constant. The applied load should be a good estimate of the rated full-load torque. The minimum current should occur at close to the rated voltage. [Reference](http://www.motorsanddrives.com/cowern/motorterms12.html)

Added material re induction generator operation:

I found a reference that shows the relationship between voltage and load with various capacitor values.
[image]

Al-Saffar, M.A.; Eui-Cheol Nho; Lipo, T.A., "Controlled shunt capacitor self-excited induction generator," in Industry Applications Conference, 1998. Thirty-Third IAS Annual Meeting. The 1998 IEEE , vol.2, no., pp.1486-1490 vol.2, 12-15 Oct. 1998

How to Estimate Rated Torque

I would first measure the motor’s shaft diameter. Compare the diameter with published data for similar motors. That should provide a range of likely values for the rated torque.

Run a dynamometer test to get data to draw a torque vs. speed curve. Before taking data get the motor near it’s rated operating temperature by running it for an hour or more at the minimum torque of the range that you estimate based on shaft diameter. When running the motor above the maximum torque in the estimated range, take data as quickly as you can to avoid overheating the motor. If possible, use automated data acquisition to get data from locked rotor through breakdown. Once you have that data, draw the curve and compare it with published curves or data for motors that might be similar. You can use that method to more closely estimate a range for rated torque.

You might be able to narrow the range by running the motor at various value of torque. At each torque value, run the motor until the temperature stabilizes and perform a temperature rise by resistance test. Unfortunately, that still will not provide an exact value for rated torque unless you know the temperature rating of the insulation used for the windings.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Just a clarification. You mentioned that the transformer should supply half the probable rated current. How is this value estimated if it is not a standard NEMA or IEC motor?

Comment: You should start by estimating the motor's ratings from its physical size by comparing with standard motors. If you have found the synchronous speed, you must have already applied some voltage. The current required for that should also give you an idea of the required current. I suppose you should consider the possibility that this is a 400 Hz aircraft motor or a special low-voltage motor made for academic purposes.

Comment: For the synchronous speed, even applying a small voltage cause it to run close to sync speed. Therefore, how can the current give an idea of required current? It is not an 400Hz aircraft motor

Comment: If I understand the procedure correctly, he is suggesting that as you increase the voltage and measure the current, you will observe an almost Ohm's law relationship, until you are above the rated voltage. At that point, the current will increase dramatically for small increases in voltage. I have not done this, but I think that is what Charles Cowie is saying, and it sounds somewhat reasonable.

Comment: That is exactly what I am suggesting. The current increase is due to saturation of the iron. The reference link that I added to my answer provides more information including an example graph. I suspect that the example shows a more dramatic change than you may find. I have never done this myself.

Comment: @Charles Cowie I have done the test according to the reference link you provided. Surprisingly, for the first induction motor i tested, the point where the currents starts to rise more than the voltage is below the rated voltage of the machine. What could be the possible problem? Higher increase in current occurs after rated voltage but initial increase is occurring below rated voltage

Comment: Since the change in slope of the curve takes place over a considerable voltage range, this test can not precisely identify the rated voltage it can only indicate an approximate voltage. The dynamometer test may provide a closer indication. Induction motor designs are never very exact.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thanks and I will note that down. As for the dynamometer test, how do I estimate the load torque which I have to keep constant? I do have a dynamometer which I can conduct the experiment on. During the experiment, what factors would change and what must be help constant other than torque?

Comment: Torque is the only parameter to hold constant. The speed will change somewhat as the voltage changes, but the change will be less near the rated voltage. You should record the speed and plot speed vs. torque. Estimate rated torque by measuring the motor and comparing the measurements with published data for standard motors. Pay particular attention to the shaft diameter. Efficiency will peak near rated voltage as shown by the Cowern reference. Power factor will change also.

Comment: @CharlesCowie For the torque, if it is found to be about 10Nm, it is obtained at rated voltage and current. ( Please correct me if I am wrong). Therefore, if 10Nm is held constant, shouldn't I be varying both the voltage and current for it to be constant? Without knowing the rated current, how do I monitor the current?

Comment: Hold the torque constant by adjusting the dynamometer load, and adjust the voltage a little bit above and below the presumed rated voltage while recording the current at the voltage test points. The minimum current should occur at close to the rated voltage. Note that I corrected that statement in my answer.

Comment: @CharlesCowie This is what I understand from your statement. Please correct if i am wrong. Adjust the voltage up and down the presumed voltage( in my case is 210V). Make sure the torque is constant at 10Nm. Whichever gives the minimum current is the rated voltage?

Comment: Yes. However, the voltage for minimum current will be close to the rated voltage, not exactly the rated voltage. The reference shows the rated voltage about 2% below the point of minimum current. The rated voltage is really a range of safe operating voltages for acceptable operating temperature and reliable motor operation. The exact voltage that provides the highest torque per amp and the highest efficiency is the optimum voltage for a given load.

Comment: I have managed to get the rated voltage of the motor. Is there any way to determine the full-load torque from these information?